# Compile java source code?

Tags: java, class, compilation

I have a java application and need to modify some function on it.
I search the source code on github. it is .java and I can see and edit with note++
after that, I compile with commandline but it said many errors and not generate the .class file.

I also extract java application to get .class file that I want to modify
I went to decompile and then compile but also get error.

so any way to compile the source code although have errors ?

I don't know why I decompile and then compile but get error ?

Here is the source code : https://github.com/OWASP/OWASP-WebScarab/blob/master/src/org/owasp/webscarab/plugin/sessionid/SessionIDAnalysis.java

I need to modify something in source code and compile to .class

I tried to compile source code without editing but still getting error that can not see the symbol.

I decompile the .class file that I extracted then compile again but still error.
the error:

[image]

I used JDK with windows command line to compile.

Comment: Well it sounds like you're not compiling it correctly - but without knowing a) the source code; b) how you're trying to compile it; c) the errors you're getting, it's really hard to help you any further. Please read [ask] and clarify your question.

Comment: You cannot compile a java file when it has compile errors. You should fix them before compiling

Comment: thanks for your comments. i will update the information

Comment: @Arashsoft as i said the source code also get error. i did not change anything :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse can compile Java classes which don't compile, though it is a very bad idea IMHO. It can replace any errors with `throw new Error("compile time error");`

You are better off;

- not trying to modify a decompiled class, try modifying the original source.
- if you do decompile a class, not all decompilers are the same. I have found FernFlower to be one of the best (it is built into Intellij)
- if the code doesn't decompile successfully, you need to patch the code so it does compile, if you want to compile it again.
- use an IDE for decompiling and recompiling (and everything else for development)

Comment: thanks for your advice

Comment: @NguyenDiep If you like you can accept or upvote this answer.